# Detect if focusout is due to a keypress or a click

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using focusout on a specific form element in order to know when a user has tabbed onward or clicked on a different field.

I need to know this because an ajax call launch immediately after this and populates several different fields (e.g. Enter a valid zip code, it searches a db and comes back with city).

Now, my question, the ajax call receives an html response and on loading it, causes the form to lose its current focus.

I need a way to save that focus and reinstate it after the ajax call.

So far, I've gotten the navigation to kind of work.  It breaks a lot, and also interferes with the loading of other things on the page (e.g. dialog windows).  So, I figure there has to be a better way to do it, which is why I'm here.  Let me know if you need more information.  Code is below.

All the best!

```
    $('.DZipCode').focusout(function () {
      var ZipCode = $('.DZipCode').val();


    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        async: false,
        type: "POST", // GET or POST
        url: "/Home/SelectZipCodeDataDestination", // the file to call`
        data: { zipCode: ZipCode },
        success: function (response) { // on success.. 
            $(":input").focus(function() {
                var prevFocus;

                prevFocus = $(this).attr("id");
               $('#quotetab').html(response);
                $('#'+prevFocus).focus();
           // });               
        }  // end of success
    });  // end of .ajax
```

});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to set a flag when a key is pressed, then just check the flag whenever you need to know.

```
var tabPressed = false;

$('input[type="text"], textarea')
    .keydown(function(e) { 
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

        tabPressed = (keyCode==9) ? true : false;
    })
    .focus(function() {
        tabPressed = false;
    });
```

Then you can do

```
if(tabPressed) {
//some stuff
}
```

in your ajax success callback (or wherever).

Comment: It took a little bit extra to get it going but the direction was definitely sound.  For some reason, the response from the ajax call was resetting my tabPressed variable to false.  I ended up just storing it's value within a secondary variable inside the focusout out function.  Thanks for the help!